# JavaScript: Make difference between ' and \'

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I'm writing a JS script that reads a text file and processes its content.
I need to detect the difference between `'` and `\'` in the input.

Any idea on how can I accomplish this?

Note that:

```
> `'` === `\'`
true
> `'`.length === `\'`.length
true
```

Comment: What do you mean by `detect the difference between ' and \'`?

Comment: let's say, I need to count the number of plain single quotes vs the escaped single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have literally a `\'` in the text file, as in backslash followed by an apostrophe, you will need to escape the backslash `\\'`.

In JS the backslash is an escape character which is why `\'` and `'` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In a JavaScript `string`, there is no difference between the two.

That's the point of escaping a character, to make sure it makes it into the string, intact.

As far as JavaScript is concerned, these 5 strings are identical:

```js
console.log('\'')
console.log("'")
console.log("\'")
console.log(`'`)
console.log(`\'`)
```